# How to show a propagator of massive spin-1 field is the Green function to its equation of motion?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions, greens-functions, propagator

During my QFT course my teacher said the propagator of the massive spin-1 field is the green function of the equation of motion derived from the Proca Lagrangian, which is shown in the next two pictures.

[image: equation of motion of A^\miu]

[image: the equation of green function]

The propagator is given by:

[image]

My major question is how to show the last equation is valid? I have tried to imitate the way that Peskin and Schroeder provided in their Chapter 2 for spin-0:

[image]

However, I am still confused since there is no commutator here, how can I use the communion relationship of the field operators. Is there another path to do this proof? If no how can I deal with the $\theta$ function and the $A^{\nu}$ field operators at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your question. If something does not make sense, you can always comment so that I can edit my answer.

You are looking at two different types of commutators. Their definitions are different, hence they represent different quantities. In the part of P&S you are reading, the authors define the retarded commutator,
$$D_R(x-y)=\theta(x^0-y^0)\langle 0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle$$
whereas in your QFT course your professor gave you the recipe for the Feynman propagator
$$D_F(x-y)=\theta(x^0-y^0)\langle 0|\phi(x)\phi(y)|0\rangle
+\theta(y^0-x^0)\langle 0|\phi(y)\phi(x)|0\rangle$$
So, you have to apply the operator
$$\eta_{\mu\nu}(\partial^2+m^2)-\partial_{\nu}\partial_{\mu}$$
on $D_F(x-y)$, given that the equation of motion holds, i.e. that $[\eta_{\mu\nu}(\partial^2+m^2)-\partial_{\nu}\partial_{\mu}] A^{\nu}(x)=0$